# AWS Lambda - trigger synchronously repeatedly until a condition has been met

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have a use case where i want a  scheduled lambda to read from a dynamodb table until there are no records left to process from its dynamodb query.  I don't want to run lots of instances of the lamdba as it will hit a REST endpoint each time and don't want to overload this external service.

The reason I am thinking i can't use dynamo streams (please correct me if I am wrong here) is
this DDB is where messages will be sent when a legacy service is down, the scheduled error handler lambda that will read them would not want to try and process them as soon as they are inserted as it is likely the legacy service is still down. (is it possible with streams to update one row in the DB say legacy_service = alive and then trigger a lambda ONLY for the rows where processed_status = false)

I also don't want to have multiple instances of the lambda running at one time as i don't want to throttle the legacy service.

I would like a scheduled lambda that queries dynamodb table for all records that have processed_status = false, the query has a limit to only retrieve a small batch (1 or 2 messages) and process them ( I have this part implemented already) when this lambda is finished i would like it to trigger again and again until there is no records in the DDB with processed_status = false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with recursive functions good tutorial here https://labs.ebury.rocks/2016/11/22/recursive-amazon-lambda-functions/